# Sorting one column in order determined by two others ('mapping')

Tags: excel, lookup

I have Excel in this format:

```
Email Id                 Name           mail
example@gmail.com        Sathish   abc@yahoo.com
abc@yahoo.com            Sandy     xyz@outlook.com
xyz@outlook.com          Satz      example@gmail.com
zyx@ymail.com            Sam       zyx@ymail.com
```

The `Name` column is related to the `Email id` column. I need to map the `Name` column according to the `mail` column which has the same content as `Email Id` but it in a different order.

"I need the Column Name in the order Of Column mail"

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? it is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @pnuts I need the Column Name in the order Of Column mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))
```

copied down.

Comment: Thanks it has been worked for me it saved lot of time thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using match and a new column.  sort the new column and your done...
[image]

Comment: I"d move column D to A and sort columns ABC independant of C.